# Beeline - No current connection - Default hs2 connection config nout found

Tags: hive, cloudera, cloudera-manager, beeline

We are facing an issue with respect to beeline CLI in one of our cloudera cluster. We are trying to connect and execute hql files which are alter statements using beeline CLI as like below and it is failing with the following errors.

```
[srvcacc@hostname ~]$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000 --verbose=true --showWarnings=true
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Beeline version 2.1.1-cdh6.1.1 by Apache Hive
Default hs2 conection config file not found
0: jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000> show databases;
No current connection
0: jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000>
```

We have tried connection using the following methods in beeline, out of 2 methods 1 of them fails and other one works.

First Method:

```
[srvcacc@hostname ~]$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000
```

Second Method:

```
[srvcacc@hostname ~]$ beeline
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Beeline version 2.1.1-cdh6.1.1 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000:
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000:
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.1.1-cdh6.1.1)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 2.1.1-cdh6.1.1)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.do>
```

the first way fails in connection with the following error

```
Default hs2 conection config file not found
0: jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000> show databases;
No current connection
```

the second way connects without any error.

We tried the connection using the -d parameter with explicit mention of driver "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" and even this gives the same error as "Default hs2 connection config not found". We also attempted the connection with "Hive CLI" (Deprecated), that works without any issue. It is needed for us to use beeline with "-u" and "-f" parameter.

Cluster information:

- 5 Nodes (One master node and 4 data nodes) cluster with CDH Version 6.1.1 on RHEL 7.5
- HiveServer2, Hive Metastore and webHcat server resides in same server (Master Node)
- Connection to hive does not have any authentication mechanism.

We have verified "HiveServer2", "HiveMetastore" services and relevant ports and web UI ports everything works with out any issue.

During our initial setup of this cluster, due to the security policies with /tmp has "noexec" configuration, we had to change the below configurations with explicit mention of "'-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/log/cloudera-scm-server/yarntemp" (where "/var/log/cloudera-scm-server" is separate mount point with 775 permissions)

```
YARN configuration

1. ApplicationMaster Java Opts Base
2. Java Configuration Options for JobHistory Server
3. Java Configuration Options for NodeManager
4. Java Configuration Options for ResourceManager

Cloudera Manager --> YARN --> search for: Gateway Client Environment Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hadoop-env.sh and add this:
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/log/cloudera-scm-server/yarntemp"
```

reference: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Problem-starting-a-nodemanager/td-p/27658

Please let us know what need to be done for beeline to work with -u and -f parameter. Any help will appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to say that using "beeline" connects and using "beeline -u xxx -f yyy it doesn't.

Looking at your logs, it seems like its coz of Username and password.

Can you try something like this

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hostname.domain.dom:10000 -n <yourname> -p <yourpassword> -f <filename.hql>
```

Comment: As you said, yes just "beeline" connects but "beeline -u jdbc:hive2://xxxxx" -f <filename.hql>" does not work. We dont have any username and password in order to connect hive. There is no authentication mechanism.

Comment: But in the logs, it's mentioned enter username and password.

Comment: Yes, it prompted for the username and password, but we did not provide anything.

Comment: Try to give "" for - u and - p in the beeline query I gave you and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It’s not working on CDH47. Its working with CDH514 version. It’s fine. We can do it with  Hive shell